# Was Kever Rachel temporary?

Tags: sources-mekorot, funeral-burial-levaya, imahot-matriarch-mothers, vayishlach

I remember hearing that Rachel Imeinu was buried in kever Rachel, but was only there for one night and then she went to Mearas Hamachpaila.

I can't remember in whose name it was said. Does anyone know a source for this?

Comment: I am remembering something like Rabbi Shlmo Kluger maybe

Comment: [Ayin Dimah - Rabbi Shlomo Kluger](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24202&st=&pgnum=3&hilite=) clearly indicates that she was buried and remained in Kever Rachel.

Comment: Doesn't Jacob Tell Joseph that he buried her there many years after he did? Why even mention it if she's in the machpelah?

Comment: Its a good question,that's why I am asking if anyone knows of it so I can look it up.

Comment: Did she move herself or she was moved by someone else in this pshat?

Comment: I would just point out that such a pshat would be arguing with Chazal on several accounts - The sifre says Yaakov did not bury Rachel in Maaras Hamachpela because he would have been embarrassed about being married to two sisters. The midrash in Bereishis Rabba (82) says that he buried her specifically there so that she would be on the route of their path into exile and pray for them. So you are looking for someone going not with Chazal.

Comment: @BabySeal, he was explaining his actions; subsequent event were irrelevant. (Alternatively, maybe he didn't know she'd moved.)

Comment: @msh210 I'd accept him not knowing, but why needlessly pain Joseph with the knowledge? I suppose you could say he wanted to fully explain himself so Joseph wouldn't suspect him if he ehard from someone else. I think there's an Inyan to do that.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that the Rabbi I heard it from might have read what Gershon Gold sourced

Comment: Either he read it wrong or he has a diff source.

Comment: The gemara Sotah 13a says that there was only room for four couples - Adam and Chavah, Avrohom and Sarah, Yitzchok and Rivkah, Ya’akov and Leah.

Comment: In the book of Samuel I, it says that Rachel is buried in the territory of Benjamin. By saying Rachel's roadside resting place was only temporary, it would reconcile the two accounts. https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15839

Comment: @ClintEastwood How would it "reconcile" which two accounts? She was buried in Benjamin outside Beit-El on the road to Bethlehem (AKA Efrata). That way when the people of Jerusalem were exiled to the north they passed by her grave. The verse ק֣וֹל בְּרָמָ֚ה נִשְׁמָע֙ means a voice is heard in Ramah the Benjemite city, not a voice is heard on high.

Comment: Today, the tomb is widely held to be just north of the old city of Bethlehem, deep in Judah. Yet the Book of Samuel indicates it is in Benjamin territory. Unless she was cut in half or tens of miles tall, she can't be buried in two places at once.
Rashi has one way of reconciling the discrepancy but the assertion that her remains were moved later is another way of doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This idea does indeed come from [R. Shlomo Kluger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Kluger). The explanation is that Rachel being buried separately was a punishment for disgracing her relationship with Yaakov by selling her marital rights to Leah for the *dudaim* that Reuven had gathered. However, since that disgrace was just for one night, her punishment of being buried separately was also only for one night, after which she was transferred to *Me'aras Hamachpelah*.

**Chochmas HaTorah, Vayishlach p. 571**

> היא מצבת קבורת רחל עד היום. יש לדייק על אמרו היא מצבת קבורת רחל מה ענין הקבורה לכאן והוי ליה לומר היא מצבת רחל עד היום אך נראה הכונה דהנה מה שלא נקברה רחל עמו הוי מטעם שאמרו חז"ל ב"ר כיון שביזתה שכיבתו של צדיק שאמרה לכן ישכב עמך הלילה דעמך הוא דמיך עמי לית הוא דמיך יע"ש ולפי זה כיון דאמרה לכן ישכב עמך הלילה א"כ לא ביזתה שכבו רק לילה אחת לכך נענשה מדה כנגד מדה שלילה אחת לא תהיה נקברת במערת המכפלה אבל אח"כ נקברה במערת המכפלה ומי קבר את משה הוא ית' לבדו כן י"ל גבי רחל דתחילת הקבורה נקברה ע"י יעקב שם בבית לחם אבל אח"כ נטלוהו מלאכי השרת וקברוה במערת המכפלה או אחר מיתת יעקב אז לילה אחת אחר שנקבר יעקב הובאה גם רחל ונקברה שם ולפ"ז העד היום לא הוי המצבה לציון על רחל ממש רק על הקבר שהקבר הוא משל רחל אך אין רחל עצמה שם וז"ש ויצב יעקב מצבת אבן על קבורתה היא מצבת קבורת רחל שאינו מצבת רחל עד היום הזה רק מצבת קבורת רחל דהקבר ישנו שם עד היום הזה אבל אין רחל שם עד היום הזה
>
> "It is the monument of the burial of Rachel until today." We can analyze the statement, "it is the monument of the burial of Rachel" —  what does burial have to do with anything here? It should have said "it is the monument of Rachel until today".
>
> But it appears that the intent is that the fact that Rachel was not buried with him was for the reason the sages said in Bereishis Rabbah, that she disgraced the lying of the righteous man for she said "therefore he will lie with you tonight" — with you he will lie in the grave but with me he will not lie in the grave.
>
> And according to this, since she said "therefore he will lie with you tonight" she therefore only disgraced his lying for one night. Therefore she was punished measure for measure that for one night she would not be buried in *Me'aras Hamachpelah*, but afterwards she was buried in *Me'aras Hamachpelah*. And who buried Moshe? God alone. So too we can say regarding Rachel that the beginning of her burial was done by Yaakov there in Bethlehem, but afterwards the ministering angels took her and buried her in *Me'aras Hamachpelah*. Or after the death of Yaakov then one night after Yaakov was buried Rachel was also brought and buried there.
>
> According to this, the "until today" is not a monument that is a reference to Rachel in actuality; it is just on the grave, because the grave was from Rachel, but Rachel herself is not there. And that which it says "and Yaakov erected a monument of stone on her grave", it is a monument to the burial of Rachel since the monument to Rachel until today is only a monument to the burial of Rachel as the grave is still there until today, but Rachel is not there until today.

Comment: Now we are left with a contradiction of Rav Kluger to Rav Kluger, unless one says that he interpreted diff in each sefer of his,meaning pshat,remez...